# How to reopen Design window of a form (Form1.cs[Design]) in a Winforms project if it is closed?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019

I accidentally closed the Designer tab (Form1.cs[Design]). How can I reopen this tab again for editing form design?

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqdZx.png)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch0pK.png)

Answer (score 2):

In the solution Explorer window (if it isn't opened then view->solution explorer).
Double click on the Form1.cs file it should have an icon like this (in VS17 and VS19)
[image: form Icon]

Or right click on Form1.cs in solution explorer -> View Designer